# How is  the SAS REPLICATE statement in PROC NLMIXED different from a FREQ statement?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, sas, weighted-sampling

Note: I do not have access to `SAS` to work this out for myself.

I'm trying to work out the difference between the `FREQ` statement in `PROC GENMOD` (for example) and the `REPLICATE` statement in `PROC NLMIXED`.

The `SAS` explanation is not illuminating the practical mathematical difference for me. The explanatory test for `REPLICATE` is ([Documentation link here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/statug_nlmixed_sect020.htm)):

> The REPLICATE statement provides a way to accommodate models in which different subjects
>   have identical data. This occurs most commonly when the dependent variable is binary. When
>   you specify a REPLICATE variable, PROC NLMIXED assumes that its value indicates the number
>   of subjects having data identical to those for the current value of the SUBJECT= variable
>   (specified in the RANDOM statement). Only the last observation of the REPLICATE variable
>   for each subject is used, and the replicate variable must have only positive integer
>   values.
>   Note that the REPLICATE mechanism is different from using a FREQ statement in other
>   statistical modeling procedures, such as PROC GLM, GENMOD, GLIMMIX, and LOGISTIC. A FREQ
>   variable is used to identify grouped values for observations, essentially multiplying the log likelihood or sum of squares contribution for the observation. A REPLICATE variable is
>   used to multiply the contribution of a subject that comprises one or more observations.

The explanatory text for `FREQ` in `PROC GENMOD` is ([Documentation link here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_genmod_sect021.htm)):

> The variable in the FREQ statement identifies a variable in the input data set containing
>   the frequency of occurrence of each observation. PROC GENMOD treats each observation as if
>   it appears *n* times, where *n* is the value of the FREQ variable for the observation. If
>   it is not an integer, the frequency value is truncated to an integer. If it is less than 1
>   or missing, the observation is not used. In the case of models fit with generalized
>   estimating equations (GEEs), the frequencies apply to the subject/cluster and therefore
>   must be the same for all observations within each subject.

Assuming the replicate variable contains only integer values, that sounds like the `REPLICATE` statement in `PROC NLMIXED` is just a `FREQ` statement. But the `SAS` documentation says otherwise. What have I missed with how the commands affect the number of observations used, and the flow on effects to estimates? In particular, how does this affect repeated measures studies?

Update: could the answer lie with differences in treatment of the degrees of freedom? I don't understand how `SAS` uses these commands to figure this out for myself.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR:
The key distinction lies in their level of operation (subject-level vs observation-level) and how they contribute to the likelihood estimation. Understanding this difference is crucial in model choice, particularly in complex models handled by `PROC NLMIXED`, and affects model estimates, standard errors, and degrees of freedom.

`REPLICATE` is used when different subjects have identical data, which often happens when the dependent variable is binary. In `PROC NLMIXED`, `REPLICATE`
indicates the number of subjects with data identical to the current `SUBJECT=` variable value. It only uses the last observation of the `REPLICATE` variable for each subject. The crucial aspect here is that the `REPLICATE` statement multiplies the log likelihood contribution of each subject rather than each individual observation which is particularly relevant for models where the subject-level replication is important, such as in clinical trials with subjects having identical binary responses.

`FREQ` identifies the frequency of occurrence of each observation. `PROC GENMOD` treats each observation as if it appears a number of times equal to the `FREQ` variable's value. This means the contribution of each observation to the log likelihood or sum of squares is multiplied by its frequency value. It's typically used to simplify datasets with repeated observations.

`REPLICATE` in `PROC NLMIXED` is suitable for situations where repeated observations across subjects are identical, focusing on subject-level replication. `FREQ` in `PROC GENMOD` is more observation-level focused.

As for degrees of freedom, I believe`PROC NLMIXED` defaults to the number of subjects minus the number of random effects for random effects models, and the number of observations otherwise. How `REPLICATE` and `FREQ` affect degrees of freedom depends on whether they increase the effective sample size at the subject or observation level, respectively.